# How to make the jQuery Sticky Float plug-in react live to page changes?

Tags: jquery, layout, position, live, sticky

I've been looking at the really rather wonderful 'stickyfloat' plug-in (http://plugins.jquery.com/files/stickyfloat_0.htm) for jQuery for a project I'm working on. I need to keep a panel on the right of the page 'in view' as the content on the left scrolls. The stickyfloat plug-in works a treat but it doesn't update it calculations if you use jQuery to effect the length of the content block in which it sits.

Is there any way I might be able to adjust this plug-in to make it respect live changes to the content div height?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059907/override-jquery-val-function   try and understand this post maybe that will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this plugin, and I have re-posted it and fixed this issue of height being changed dynamically after the plugin was initiated, check this out:

http://dropthebit.com/74/sticky-floating-box/