# How to fake jquery.ajax() response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unit-testing, testing

I am writing some QUnit tests for a JavaScript that makes AJAX calls.

For isolation I overwrite `$.ajax` to write the parameter array of an AJAX call to a variable. This works to test how methods use AJAX functions, but I have difficulty testing the success handler of [`$.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

From the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/load/:

> When a successful response is detected (i.e. when textStatus is "success" or "notmodified"), .load() sets the HTML contents of the matched element to the returned data.

So I have attempted to return an object containing objects with the same name as variables for the success handler:

```
    //Mock ajax function
    $.ajax = function (param) {
        _mockAjaxOptions = param;
        var fakeAjaxSuccess = { responseText: "success", textStatus: "success", XMLHttpRequest: "success" };
        return fakeAjaxSuccess;
    };
```

But this approach hasn't worked.

How can I replicate the behaviour of a successful AJAX call?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After reading inspired by @Robusto and @Val, I found a method that works:

```
//Mock ajax function
$.ajax = function (param) {
    _mockAjaxOptions = param;
    //call success handler
    param.complete("data", "textStatus", "jqXHR");
};
```

Instead of raising the event from any real $.ajax code or by triggering any events, I have my fake ajax object call the function (which is passed in as a parameter to `$.ajax()`) as part of my fake function.

Comment: I would have done the same thing although I hid the $.ajax call behind another method to make it easier to swap out in my tests.

Comment: Although it's maybe late, but you might have been looking for https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax

Comment: @xhh that's a pretty good framework for setting up return values.

Comment: @PeterSmith why did you add another function? Since JS is dynamically typed you can just overwrite it in situ. Did it give you any benefits other than encapsulation?

Comment: And what exactly do you do with this `_mockAjaxOptions` undeclared variable that seems to hang in the air?

Comment: If I recall correctly, I declared `_mockAjaxOptions` outside of this and inspected it in the assert step of a test.

Comment: Is there any way to do this with Sinon?

Comment: @frogbandit A lot's changed in two years and lot of ajax is baked into js frameworks, that would be a good question independently

Comment: @xhh that's a pretty neat framework, maybe its a good contemporary answer instead of getting lost in a comment (I don't mind posting it myself if ur busy)

Answer (score 29):

This question has a few years and for the new versions of jQuery has changed a bit.

To do this with Jasmin you can try [Michael Falaga's approach](https://michaelfalanga.com/post/mock-jquery-ajax-calls-with-jasmine/)

**Solution**

```
  function ajax_response(response) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred().resolve(response);
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

**With Jasmine**

```
  describe("Test test", function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
      spyOn($, 'ajax').and.returnValue(
        ajax_response([1, 2, 3])
      );
    });
    it("is it [1, 2, 3]", function() {
      var response;
      $.ajax('GET', 'some/url/i/fancy').done(function(data) {
        response = data;
      });
      expect(response).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
    });
  });
```

**No Jasmine**

```
  $.ajax = ajax_response([1, 2, 3]);
  $.ajax('GET', 'some/url/i/fancy').done(function(data) {
     console.log(data); // [1, 2, 3]
  });
```

Comment: +one Thank you very much.

Comment: I get `ajax is not a function` is: `{state: ƒ, always: ƒ, catch: ƒ, pipe: ƒ...`

Comment: @Toskan I had the same problem. I assume this answer was correct in 2015, but as of my writing today the "return deferred.promise();" line returns an OBJECT. You want to change this to "return deferred.promise;", so it returns the promise FUNCTION.

Comment: do not use deferred: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783936/keep-getting-error-deferred-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 12):

### Use a closure to override `$.ajax` with a dummy response

After trying [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5275143/2502532) and [the answer posted by user1634074](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29680013/2502532), I devised this simple and flexible blend of the two.

**In its most basic form…**

```
function ajax_response(response) {
  return function (params) {
    params.success(response);
  };
}
$.ajax = ajax_response('{ "title": "My dummy JSON" }');
```

In the above example, define a function `ajax_response()` that accepts some JSON string as an argument (or any number of custom arguments useful for simulating a response) and returns an anonymous closure function that will be assigned to `$.ajax` as an override for unit testing.

The anonymous function accepts a `params` argument which will contain the settings object passed to the `$.ajax` function. And it uses the argument(s) passed to the outer function to simulate a response from the server. In this example, it always simulates a successful response from the server, by simply invoking the `success` callback and supplying it with the dummy JSON.

**It is easy to reconfigure…**

```
function ajax_response(response, success) {
  return function (params) {
    if (success) {
      params.success(response);
    } else {
      params.error(response);
    }
  };
}

// Simulate success
$.ajax = ajax_response('{ "title": "My dummy JSON." }', true); 
doAsyncThing(); // Function that calls $.ajax

// Simulate error
$.ajax = ajax_response('{ "error": "Who is the dummy now?" }', false); 
doAsyncThing(); // Function that calls $.ajax
```

**Below we can see it in action…**

```js
/* FUNCTION THAT MAKES AJAX REQUEST */
function doAsyncThing() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "somefile.php",
    // data: {…},
    success: function (results) {
      var json = $.parseJSON(results),
          html = $('#ids').html();
      $('#ids').html(html + '<br />' + json.id);
    }
  });
}

/* BEGIN MOCK TEST */
// CREATE CLOSURE TO RETURN DUMMY FUNCTION AND FAKE RESPONSE
function ajax_response(response) {
  return function (params) {
    params.success(response);
  };
}

var n = prompt("Number of AJAX calls to make", 10);

for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
  
  // OVERRIDE $.ajax WITH DUMMY FUNCTION AND FAKE RESPONSE
  $.ajax = ajax_response('{ "id": ' + i + ' }');
  doAsyncThing();
}
/* END MOCK TEST */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="ids">IDs:</p>
```

Answer (score 6):

## Mock $.ajax as needed without disturbing jQuery

The answers here are good but had a specific need to build out a fake response to a single API call while leaving all other API calls the same until the backend service was built out so I can continue building stuff on the UI.

The API object uses $.ajax under the hood so you can call an API method like so:

```
api.products({ price: { $lt: 150, tags: ['nike', 'shoes'] } })
.done(function(json) {
  // do something with the data
})
.error(function(err) {
  // handle error
});
```

This method does the trick:

```
function mockAjax(options) {
  var that = {
    done: function done(callback) {
      if (options.success)
        setTimeout(callback, options.timeout, options.response);
      return that;
    },
    error: function error(callback) {
      if (!options.success)
        setTimeout(callback, options.timeout, options.response);
      return that;
    }
  };
  return that;
}
```

Then override a single api call without touching $.ajax:

```
api.products = function() {
  return mockAjax({
    success: true,
    timeout: 500,
    response: {
      results: [
        { upc: '123123', name: 'Jordans' },
        { upc: '4345345', name: 'Wind Walkers' }
      ]
    }
  });
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lsf3ezaz/2/

Answer (score 1):

Look at the jQuery documentation: You'll see that the Ajax setup provides a number of other conditions that are tested for. If you make them all point to your fakeAjaxSuccess, you might achieve for your objective.

Alternatively, wrap your `$.ajax` call into its own function and have whatever calls it simply call your event handler with the `fakeAjaxSuccess` object.

Answer (score 1):

I think the link below should help. as for a parameter I am not so sure but it could be .

```
$.fn.ajax.success =  function (){
  ///the rest goest here
}
```

[Override jQuery .val() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059907/override-jquery-val-function)

Comment: doesn't make any sense...the browser would still do a request. this only overrides  the success function it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple working solution

```
var set_ajax_response = function(data){
  $.ajax = $.Deferred().resolve(data).promise;
}

var data = [1,2,3];

set_ajax_response(data);
```

Comment: do not use deferred: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63783936/keep-getting-error-deferred-is-not-a-function