# How to clear ajaxSetup after each use?

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a very simple xhr mock example and need the ability to setup the return success (also in this specific example I can't use a library).

```
  function fakeHttpRequest(json) {                                                      
    $.ajaxSetup({
      complete: function() {
        this.success.call(this, json);
      }
    });
  }
```

What I'm doing above works great except that if I call it 3 times, the last integration test I'm using this in returns 3 different times (instead of the 1 as I expected). Is it possible to invoke this and clear it or reset it between tests?

**Update**

Here is what I ended up with

```
function fakeHttpRequest(json) {
   jQuery.ajax = function(opts) {
     opts.success(json);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to fake ajax success response, you can always fake it ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272698/how-to-fake-jquery-ajax-response)):

```
var fakeResponse;

$.ajax = function( options ) {
  options.success( fakeResponse );
}
```

You only need to set the fakeResponse before having an object call $.ajax and it will call the object's `success` function.

Comment: Even after putting the $.ajaxSetup() in my setup or teardown (QUnit) I see multiple logs when a single test runs and the production code hits $.getJSON directly. (shown above in my question)

Comment: is there a better way to achieve this? I simply need to fake the success of an xhr when doing $.getJSON in production code (and something that can safely be reset between tests) ?