# Keep getting error: $.deferred is not a function

Tags: jquery, typescript, react-native, jquery-deferred, openapi-generator

I've installed jquery and @types/jquery. I want to use jquery.Deferred() but when i try to use it I get error that "$.Deferred is not a function".

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
u
// somewhere in code
let dfd = $.Deferred<
      { response: JQueryXHR; body?: any },
      { response: JQueryXHR; errorThrown: string }
    >();
```

It is from code that was generated by https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator for typescript. I'm using it in React Native app. Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: `$.Deferred` is virtually obsolete now in modern browsers due to built in Promise API

Comment: Use `Promise` instead of `$.Deferred`. If you want to return a value that has been deferred, return `Promise.resolve(someValue)`. If you want to return a deferred error, `Promise.reject(someError)`. Etc.