I have inputs types of checkbox and when I perform delete or retrieve methods it works but page is not reload
In my Asp.Net Mvc project, I have checkbox type inputs and I get the Ids of items through them by using jquery and send them controller by using ajax. Methods are working but after work the page is not reload so I can see the result only reload page manuel.
function takeIds() {
    var selected = [];
    $('#checkDiv input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function () {
        selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
    });

    var messageIds = selected.join(',');
    console.log("messageIds: ", messageIds); // Konsolda messageIds'yi kontrol etmek için

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("RetrieveMessage", "WriterPanelMessage")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ messageIds: messageIds }),
        timeout: 10000,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log("AJAX Success: ", result);
            if (result === 'Ok') {
                location.reload()
            } else {
                alert('Mesaj geri alma işlemi başarısız oldu.');
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.error("AJAX Error: ", textStatus, errorThrown);
            alert('Bir hata oluştu.');
        }
    });
}

   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<JsonResult> RetrieveMessage(string messageIds)
   {
       try
       {
           string p = (string)Session["WriterMail"];
           string[] Ids = messageIds.Split(',');
           List<Message> messages = messageManager.GetListInbox(p);

           if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageIds) && Ids.Length > 0)
           {
               foreach (var item in messages)
               {
                   foreach (var id in Ids)
                   {
                       if (item.MessageID == Convert.ToInt32(id))
                       {
                           item.IsDeleted = false;
                           await messageManager.Update(item);
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Yönlendirme yapılacak: DeletedMessages");
           return Json(new { result = "Ok" });
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hata oluştu: " + ex.Message);
           return Json(new { result = "Fail" });
       }
   }


ajax will never reload the page automatically. Standard form submits do reload the page.

what does your console.log("AJAX Success: ", result); report?

using ajax makes you delete the DOM in success callback or call reload method like what you do.

@MarkSchultheiss result is Ok

@TinyWang have any advice ?

because the html is rendered in the server side, my advice is reload the page manually just like what you already do. if we manually delete the target DOM, then there will be missing several items in your page.

You action returns correct response code (200) every time even if your process was broken. You have to return Badrequest from catch exception with message like this return BadRequest(new { result = "bad request"}) and json response(code 200) from end of successfull action,ex: return Json(new { result = "Ok" }). This helps properly ajax which one correct action result of request, and then processed you result with reload page or show error toast of operation.

@ISR BadRequest does not appear when I type.

@Oğuzhan yes you have to change return type of Action from JsonResult to IActionResult and return  as return Ok(new JsonResult(new { result = "OK" })) and BadRequest(new { result = "Fail" });

I thought it and change return type ActionResult but still does not appear also IActionResult. @ISR

@Oğuzhan just try to set  to check action return response
success: function(response) {
alert('OK');
},
error: function(xhr) {
alert('ERR');
}

I solved the problem by using window.location.href instead of location.reload()

I did this pretty fast and mocked up the ajax part just to show the action (gives a blank screen after a short delay) if you check something to post.
Here are some details re: the issue at hand.
Instance methods

window.location.reload();
This is an instance method and will reload the current URL - like a Refresh button in a browser; Reloads with the POST data whereas .href does not
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload

window.location.replace(url);
Replaces current resource with the provided required URL - user will not be able to use the BACK button to return to the current URL as the url will not be in the session history
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace


Instance properties:

window.location.href = url; a "stringifier" that returns the url as a string or allows the href to be updated, Basic difference from .href and .replace() is the href is stored in the session history meaning the user can navigate back using the BACK button in the browser. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href Special note - the .href will not reload if there is a hash property in the URL Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash

SO given all that info ^^ suggestion is to use
window.location.href = window.location.href;


function takeIds(event) {
  const container = $(this).closest('.message-container');
  const checks = container
    .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
    .filter(':checked');
  let info = `<div>${container.data("postaddress")}</div><div>${( !checks.length ? "Nothing checked!" :
    `Good: ${checks.length} checked!`)}</div>`;
  $('.information')
    .toggleClass('error', !checks.length)
    .html(info);

  if (!checks.length) {
    return;
  }
  // could do this or the map only
  //let selected = [];
  //checks.each(function() {
  //   selected.push($(this).val());
  //});
  let selected = checks.map((i, ck) => ck.value).toArray();
  let messageIds = selected;
  $('.information')
    .toggleClass('error', false)
    .html($('.information').html() + `[${messageIds}]`);
  $.ajax({
    url: container.data("postaddress"),
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: messageIds,
    timeout: 10000
  }).done(function(result) {
    let msg = `<div>AJAX Success:${JSON.stringify(result)}</div>`;
    if (result.ok) {
      msg = msg + "<div class='error'>We are good here we will reload shortly...</div>";
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.href = window.location.href;
      }, 5000);

    } else {
      msg = msg + '<div>Mesaj geri alma işlemi başarısız oldu. Woops</div>';
      // alert('Mesaj geri alma işlemi başarısız oldu.');
    }
    $('.information')
      .toggleClass('error', false)
      .html($('.information').html() + msg);
  }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    let msg = `<div>AJAX Error:${textStatus}Error:${errorThrown}</div>`;
    $('.information')
      .toggleClass('error', true)
      .html($('.information').html() + msg);
    // alert('Bir hata oluştu.');
  });
}
$('.message-container').on('click', '.testerout', takeIds);

/* below here is my fake ajax mock 
  I did not invent this. Leveraged some info from here https://stackoverflow.com/q/5272698/125981 */
function mockAjax(options) {
  var that = {
    done: function done(callback) {
      if (options.success)
        setTimeout(callback, options.timeout, options.response);
      return that;
    },
    fail: function error(callback) {
      if (!options.success)
        setTimeout(callback, options.timeout, options.response);
      return that;
    }
  };
  return that;
}
/* Then override api call without touching $.ajax: */
WriterPanelMessage = function() {
  return mockAjax({
    success: true,
    timeout: 500,
    response: {
      results: {
        result: 'Ok'
      }
    }
  });
};
/* Then override api call without touching $.ajax: */
WriterPanelMessage = function() {
  return mockAjax({
    success: false,
    timeout: 500,
    response: {
      results: {
        result: 'Oh No'
      }
    }
  });
};

$.ajax = function() {
  return mockAjax({
    success: true,
    response: {
      ok: true
    },
    timeout: 500
  });
};
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
}

.message-container,
.information {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 2em;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5em;
  justify-content: center;
  border: solid 1px #00FF00;
  background-color: #00FF0040;
  border-radius: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.message-container .testerout {
  border-radius: 2em;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

.information>* {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.information.error,
.information .error {
  border: solid 1px #FF0000;
  background-color: #FF000010;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- actual <div id="checkDiv" class="message-container" data-postaddress="@Url.Action("RetrieveMessage", "WriterPanelMessage")">-->
<div id="checkDiv" class="message-container" data-postaddress="WriterPanelMessage\RetrieveMessage">
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="cheers"/>Cheers</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="speech"/>Speeches</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="yells"/>Yells</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="whisper"/>Whisper</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" value="quiet"/>Silence</label>
  <button class="testerout" type="button">Test Our Code</button>
</div>
<div class="information"></div>



