# Catch input change caused by jQuery

Tags: jquery

is there a method in jquery that allows to catch when field is modified by script?

This only works when input field modified by hands

```
$('input[name=myInput]').change(function() { ... });
```

so as this

```
$('input[name=myInput]').on('input', function() { ... });
```

I want an event listener for this field to be able to catch this:

```
 $('input[name=myInput]').val('changed_value');
```

Comment: `$('input[name=myInput]').val('changed_value').trigger('change');` is the simplest way

Comment: the change event will be fired only when a user interaction changes the value of an input field, when a script changes the value it is not fired...

Comment: Though i can't say it's the most efficient method, 'watching' the `input` field ([as suggested in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery)) by using `setInterval()` is a solution

Comment: If you're programatically changing it, then why would you need a listener?  Maybe you're over-thinking this. See very first comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also do as A. Wolff says, which is best way :

`$('input[name=myInput]').val('changed_value').trigger('change');`

Though, if you really want it to always trigger a change event when you programatically change it (but i don't recommend it !), you could override jQuery val function with something like this :

```
(function ($) {
  var originalVal = $.fn.val;
  $.fn.val = function(value) {
    if (typeof value != 'undefined') {
        // setter
        originalVal.call(this, value);
        this.trigger('change');
    }else{
        // getter
        return originalVal.call(this, value);
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2059948/1665540)